# How to downgrade Java. For example Java 7u72 to 7u67

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk, jre

How can I downgrade java 7 to update 67 as suggested by this [Check Point issue](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk103353)?

I need this to install Check Point VPN.

I have to install `Java 7u67`. How can I do it? How can I install specific version of Java.

Now I have `Java 8u25` and `Java 7u72` when I install with the default installer.

I have this issue using Ubuntu 14.10.

Answer (score 8):

### Download

Go to [official java download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), scroll down to the bottom of the page until you see **Previous Releases**. Click Download

[image]

Choose `Java SE 7` on the next page and you will see [web-page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html) where you can choose specific Java version. If you unsure what to choose, choose **Development Kit** - it will cover all your needs

[image]

Now you will get [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html#jdk-7u67-oth-JPR) page. And you see something like screenshot below. Choose `tar.gz` depending on your architecture, I highlighted two of them that fits Ubuntu:

[image: picking java]

*Oracle may ask you to sign up before download*

---

### Installation

Now you have file `jdk*.tar.gz`. [Here is great manual](https://askubuntu.com/a/55960/164083) about installing java. I took out the instruction and changed it a little bit.

- Uncompress `.tar.gz`

  `tar -xvf jdk*`

The JDK package is extracted into `jdk.xxx` directory. Check carefully this folder name, because we will use it the next step. **I'm assuming that path to this new extracted folder is `path_to_jdk_folder` and folder name is `folder_name`, you should manually change it before executing commands below.**

Usually it is:

> path_to_jdk_folder - **/home/c0rp/Downloads/jdk1.7.0**
>
> folder_name - **jdk1.7.0**

- Installing

Run `sudo update-alternatives --list java` to check if you have configured java already.

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --list java
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45_x586/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/java
```

**If it is saying `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for java` run this set of commands**. Don't forget replace `path_to_jdk_folder` and `folder_name`:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm
sudo mv path_to_jdk_folder /usr/lib/jvm/folder_name
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/folder_name/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/folder_name/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/folder_name/bin/javaws" 1
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/java
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javac
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javaws
```

**If there is no errors and your java list is not empty, run this set of commands**.  Don't forget replace `path_to_jdk_folder` and `folder_name`:

```
LNUM=$[$(update-alternatives --list java | wc -l) + 1]
sudo mv path_to_jdk_folder /usr/lib/jvm/folder_name
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/folder_name/bin/java" "$LNUM"
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/folder_name/bin/javac" "$LNUM"
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/folder_name/bin/javaws" "$LNUM"
```

- Run

  ```
  sudo update-alternatives --config java
  ```

You will see output similar to the one below - choose the number of new `jdk1.7.0 (folder_name)` - for example `2` in this list (unless you have have never installed Java in your computer in which case a sentence saying `There is nothing to configure` will appear):

```
    $ sudo update-alternatives --config java
    There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java                   1         manual mode
* 3            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/java                   1         manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode
```

Repeat the above for:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
```

### Check installation

```
java -version
```